# Doubts about black formatting in python

Tags: python, formatter

I'm configurating Visual Studio Code or Python programming, using PyLint as linter and Black as a formatter.

I could configure for auto-formating when save but i was wondering if there is a way to "tell" black to use the variable name convention for PEP8...  for example, if detects a constant to change automatically to upper case, if it's a variable that is in camel case that converts it to snake_case, etc..

This is my settings.json:

```
{
   "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
   "python.linting.pycodestyleArgs": [
        "--max-line-length=90"
    ],
   "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
   "python.formatting.provider": "black",
   "[python]":{
          "editor.formatOnSabe":true,
    },
   "python.linting.enabled": true,
```

Hope someone knows how to help me.. i've been searching in a lot of pages through the internet >.<

Thank you!

Comment: Black is purely a syntax formatter. It has no way of knowing whether something is a constant or a variable, and it isn't targetted at refactoring your code.  You might want to look at a refactorer like rope, although I've never tried using it for this kind of thing. Or you could just make sure you (and all contributors) follow a style guide.

Comment: Note that python doesn't even have a notion of a 'constant'.  By convention we call variables *we* won't change 'constant', but there's no `const` in python (there is in MicroPython, but that does somethig different).  So no python tool is going to be able to detect infallibly if X is a constant or not.

Comment: Also there's a typo in your json: `Sabe -> Save`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! :D
yes haha i saw the typo but i wrote it wrong when traspassing to this question, in json is with V :D 

I'll look for "rope"  but i'm sure we are going to end up following a style guide with my team.